# Is it possible to add multiple video streams to the same Peer Connection object?

Tags: webrtc

I was wondering, would it be possible to add more than one stream to a `Peer Connection` object using the `addStream()` function and to receive it at the other end using the `onAddStream` function?

I'm trying to forward all the remote streams available to a particular peer to all other connected peers. Essentially setting up a Video Conferencing system where one peer acts as the 'Hub'.

Comment: Yeah -- you can add multiple streams to a single peer object --- and access them later using "peer.localStreams[index]" or "peer.remoteStreams[index]" ---

Comment: But for some reason, it does not work. As in, the remote peer cannot access the second remote stream.

Comment: Oh yeah, it is still an "open issue" because "video freezes with multiple streams on single peer connection" and Chrome WebRTC team is working to solve it. (there are still some hidden gotchas out there to support this feature)...

Comment: @MuazKhan - Is this issue has been resolved? if not what is the option for it? I would like to share my screen and video/audio.

Comment: @Krishna I want to achieve the same. Is there any update right now?

Comment: @MuazKhan Is it possible now?